# Convert string (long date and time in 12-hour format) to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How can I convert a datetime string like `December 13, 2015 09:55 PM` to a `DateTime`?

Comment: please add appropriate tags.

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.Parse(string)`?

Comment: Or `DateTime.ParseExact` with an appropriate format? There are *lots* of date/time conversion questions on Stack Overflow - please research them to give you a starting point, and if you can't make progress, show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strDate = "December 13, 2015 09:55 PM";
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse("December 13, 2015 09:55 PM")`